# Extract string between two words in c#

Tags: c#

I have this string inside text file " *****.********* start *****.********* aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa adddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddd end *****.********* start *****.********* frfrffrfrffr bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb gggggggggggggggg end *****.********* start *****.********* ppppppppppwpw hhhhheeehheee mmmmmmmmmmeem end " And I want get each part between start word and end word to specific string variable
Like 
String first="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa adddddddddddddddd dddddddddddddd";
String second="frfrffrfrffr bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb gggggggggggggggg ";

Comment: Hello! Please read [ask], your question is currently unclear. Please explain a bit further what you want to do and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like `Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");` which would strip out anything that is not a letter.

Or, you could pass in the strings and strip out all the non-letter characters, like this.

```
public static bool IsAllLetters(string s)
{
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!Char.IsLetter(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is in memory you can split it on the new line using something like this

```
var split = inputString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The you just need to iterate through items in split. In the loop search for "start", skip the next line, then append the following lines together till you hit "end". And I guess you would skip blank lines as well if there wouldn't be blank lines in the text you want to keep.

Comment: I've seen people use `inputString.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n",  Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);` instead as a catch-all for new-lines.